# How to compare Time in java/android (given input in strings)?

Tags: java, android

I have two strings which are used to store time in the format **hh:mm**.I want to the compare these two to know which time is greater.Which is the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, if they're *actually* hh:mm (including leading zeroes, and in 24-hour format) then you can just compare them lexicographically (i.e. using `String.compareTo(String)`). That's the benefit of a sortable format :)

Of course, that won't check that both values are valid times. If you need to do that, you should probably parse both times: check the length, check the colon, parse two substrings, and probably multiply the number of hours by 60 and add it to the number of minutes to get a *total* number of minutes. Then you can compare those two totals.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, if you *do* need to parse the values for whatever reason, personally I would recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) (possibly a cut down version, given the mobile nature) rather than `SimpleDateTimeFormat` and `Date`. Joda Time is a much nicer date and time API than the built-in one.

Comment: Great Answer.The simple string comparison was what i wanted here.Btw i guess we can  compare dates in the same way if we are using the appropriate format such as (yyyy-mm-dd).isn't it?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @rogerstone: I've added my answer, which is showing you how to compare dates.

Comment: @rogerstone: Yes, if you store dates in yyyy-MM-dd, and date/times in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format, you can always sort lexicographically.

Comment: I really think you should use SimpleDateFormat and Date. Comparing strings will invevitably end up in a mess, e.g. if your somehow end up using invalid values, as you have no error handling.

Comment: @hpe: It depends whether there's already validation elsewhere. If you can trust the values but for whatever reason still have them as strings (which can definitely happen) then there's no need to reparse them. If you *do* need to parse them, I'd use Joda Time rather than SimpleDateFormat :)

Comment: Of course it's not strictly necessary to reparse them, but the classes are there for a reason, and this seemed a little more tedious than just using the Date/SDF classes: "[..]should probably parse both times: check the length, check the colon, parse two substrings, and probably multiply the number of hours by 60 [..]" . And of course, Joda Time would be the preferable way to deal with time (and hopefully soon will be the standard way), but importing a 500kB library for this little task strikes me as a little overkill - especially in an Android-application. ;)

Comment: @hpe: Hence the "possibly a cut down version" part... and I tend to find that programs don't use dates and times just for a *single* operation in the whole program. It's easy to start off that way, and gradually do more and more without ever taking the step to use a decent library. I take your point about the manual version being a little more tedious than using SimpleDateFormat though.

Comment: @Jon: Are there any cut down versions of JT? Also, I've read that JT does not perform well with Android. But; whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: @hpe: I read *one* question about that, and I asked for feedback around reading the time zone database (which is the cause of the delay, I suspect)... but I never heard back. I don't know of any cut down versions, but it should be possible to cut out quite a bit of it, I suspect. I wonder if there'd be much call for that... could be quite an interesting little project.

Comment: Wouldn't midnight make things difficult for a lexicographic comparison? We know that 00:00 could be after 23:59 but using String.compareTo() would tell us that 23:59 is only after 00:00.

Comment: @TJThind: Well if you're going to wrap around to another day then *any* time can be after any other. Is 11am after 10am? Not if we're talking about *tomorrow's* 10am.

Answer (score 23):

Use the SimpleDateFormat and Date classes. The latter implements Comparable, so you should be able to use the .compareTo() method to do the actual comparison. Example:

```
            String pattern = "HH:mm";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            try {
                Date date1 = sdf.parse("19:28");
                Date date2 = sdf.parse("21:13");

                // Outputs -1 as date1 is before date2
                System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));

                // Outputs 1 as date1 is after date1
                System.out.println(date2.compareTo(date1));

                date2 = sdf.parse("19:28");         
                // Outputs 0 as the dates are now equal
                System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));

            } catch (ParseException e){
                // Exception handling goes here
            }
```

See the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Would be useful in the future for me

Comment: Now date class has other methods like 
openTime.before(currentTime)

Answer (score 3):

I have written functions for this before in my Android program and I will gladly share the source below.

Functions (will explain later using "how to use" code):

```
public static void String setFormattedTimeString(final String formatExpr,
                                   final long timeStampInSeconds) {     
    final Date dateFromTimeStamp = new Date(timeStampInSeconds);        
    final SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatExpr);
    final String formattedDateInString = simpleformat.format(dateFromTimeStamp);        
    return formattedDateInString;
}

public static void Calendar setCalendar(final int year, final int month,
                                    final int day) {            
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();           
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    return calendar;            
}

public static void double timeDifferenceInDays(final Calendar firstDate,
                                     final Calendar secondDate) {
    final long firstDateMilli = firstDate.getTimeInMillis();
    final long secondDateMilli = secondDate.getTimeInMillis();
    final long diff = firstDateMilli - secondDateMilli;   

    // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 because I want the difference in days. Change
    // as your wish. 
    final double diffDays = (double) diff / (double) (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return diffDays;
}
```

And this is how I use them to calculate difference (days in this example). In this example I'm assuming you have a **timestamp** to use, otherwise you can change easily:

```
// Here you maybe have a timestamp in seconds or something..    

// This is ONE Calendar.
final String yearString = MyToolClass.setFormattedTimeString("y", timestamp);
final int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);                                                   
final String monthString = MyToolClass.setFormattedTimeString("M", timestamp);
final int month = Integer.parseInt(monthString);                                      
final String day_in_monthString = MyToolClass.setFormattedTimeString("d",
                                        timestamp);
final int day_of_month = Integer.parseInt(day_in_monthString);

final Calendar calendarOne = MyToolClass.setCalendar(year, month,
                                        day_of_month);   

// Same stuff for Calendar two.

// Calculate difference in days.
final double differenceInDays = MyToolClass.timeDifferenceInDays(calendarOne,
                                        calendarTwo);
```

Comment: Thanks victor.Although this is not the easiest way around,I will keep this in mind.